# jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park (Native method) crash in android app

Tags: java, android, android-activity, architecture, crash

I am facing this issue in android app
jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park (Native method)

There are several answers in stackoverflow but i need in android specific way

```
main (waiting): tid=1 systid=14525 
   at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native method)
   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:885)
   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:917)
   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1240)
   at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:267)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabe.zai(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabd.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:2)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabx.onReceive(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:4)
   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1752)
   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(unavailable:2)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8191)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
```

Comment: Suddenly this crash is logged in Firebase Crashlytics. This crash is happens only Android 12 devices. @RockyGlobal have you got any solution?

Comment: Yes i too got this crash so added this question so that i can get some solutions

Comment: No still waiting

Comment: It's not a crash in my case but an ANR

Comment: Ya any way of handling it

Comment: do you use Firebase Messaging or any other local/remote notification solution? I am also looking for the ANR problem.

Comment: @RockyGlobal Did you fix this ANR? Could you please share if there's a workaround?

Comment: Any progress on this issue ?

Comment: this error is coming in chinese devices.

Comment: Seems something like the application is not being cleaned up with window.destroy override and needs System.exit(0); as the final line of the window.close listener. Basically seems like someone simply presses the window close button or swipes the app out.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue too. In my case it was an ANR caused by not properly requesting location. I was using an outdated library to do that. Once I moved out of the library and used the Android recommended way of querying the current location it worked fine.

Problematic Library: https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation

Android recommended way of querying current location: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).